# GMSMapView - how to get callback when map did end moving from scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps-sdk-ios

I need to get a callback from GMSMapView when it stopped moving.

I have read the documentation and i have found "mapView:idleAtCameraPosition:" method, but it's not quite what i'm looking for. This method gets called too often, not just when the mapView did end moving.

Any idea?

Answer (score 13):

Add a boolean to track whether the map has started being dragged. Then on mapView:willMove: set it to true. In idleAtCameraPosition, only update if this variable is true:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, idleAtCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition!) {
    if locationDragged == true {
        locationDragged = false
        println("changed position: \(mapView.camera.target)")
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe record the position of the camera in `mapView:idleAtCameraPosition:`. Then on the next call, if the position hasn't changed, ignore the call. If the position has changed, then you know the map has moved and stopped again, and so you can do whatever processing you need - and store the new position in the member again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a NSTimer instance variable that trigger your callback method after a given delay when stops "mapView:didChangeCameraPosition:" invocation.   like this:

first set an instance variable:

```
     NSTimer *timerScroll;
```

then:

```
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapViewW didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
{    
    if (timerScroll) {
        [timerScroll invalidate];
    }
    timerScroll=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(drawMarkers) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```